# Doing Bluetooth operation in Today view

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on Bluetooth Low Enrgy (BLE) supported iOS application which will have below functionalities

- Sending data over BLE
- receving data from BLE
- Verifying connection (BLE) status

I want to create Today view (notification bar).

Can we above operation in Today view using BLE api?
Is there any limitation/ constrains?

Regards,

Phill